# How to retrieve complete Data from the folders that has subfolders. in minio?

Tags: python, minio

using
objects = s3Client.list_objects("sample", "samplefolder/sample1")

i managed to get into the folder,
but i want to print/download the files in the folders that is sorted out with timestamp subfolders.

any idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: probably you will have to get all filenames and dates in folder, and print/download every file separatelly. And if you will have subfolder then you will have to repeate it for subfolder - so you will need recursion.

Comment: can you help write a sample code ? thank so much in advance

Comment: I don't use S3. I only know that other services usually need this method to get something more than single file.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `recursive` parameter will do the trick – returns a flat list of paths.

```
objects = client.list_objects(minio_bucket, folder_name, recursive=True)
```